# Overlaying two pandas Dataframes or numpy arrays and creating a key-value dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, overlay

I have two CSV files of shape lets say 3x3.

File 1 looks like this:

```
-1, 2,-1
-1,-1, 3
-1, 8, 9
```

and File 2 like this:

```
-1, 56,-1
-1,-1,  73
-1, 24, 100
```

My aim is to overlay both arrays or `DataFrame`s and create a dictionary of the following form:

```
dict = {2:56, 3:73, 8:24, 9:100}
```

I can create something loop-based but I am wondering if there is a way of masking or overlaying the arrays and creating the respective dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flatten the dataframes, drop the null values, and dict/zip them:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the data, converting -1 to NaN
dfa = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', header=None, na_values=[-1])
dfb = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', header=None, na_values=[-1])

# Flatten the dataframes
a = dfa.values.flatten()
b = dfb.values.flatten()

# Remove null values and cast back to ints (if that matters)
# Note that both are filtered according to the key data
a = a[~np.isnan(a)].astype(int)
b = b[~np.isnan(a)].astype(int)

# Zip to pair the lists, then convert to a dict
d = dict(zip(a, b))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Floriand no problem!  If it fixed your issue, you can accept the answer so people know it's solved, and if you liked the answer, you can upvote it (though neither are required!).